# How can I speed up a tryCatch function in R?

Tags: r, try-catch

I am trying to predict a test data set from a model in R. There are missing factors, so I would like to skip or replace only those when I am creating my output. What I have come up with is

```
safe.predict = function(x){
  output = tryCatch({
    predict(best.model, test.data.ffdf[x,])
  }, error = function(e) {
    0.50
  })
  return(output)
}#end safe.predict

output = sapply(1:nrow(test.data.ffdf), safe.predict)
```

This way if there is an error (ie additional factors) I could replace just that value with 0.5 or NA or even use another model. The problem is that it takes forever. I have a 6M long dataset and it's looking like it will take about 7 days to run (based on calcs from smaller datasets). Running the same with just predict() would take less than an hour with no error catching.

So what am I doing wrong? The approach looks vectorized to me, but it is running slower than a for() loop.

Edits: removing the values from the dataset is difficult since at this point I have access to the model, but not necessarily the training data set. Additionally there may be factors in the test set that simply weren't present in any of the training sets available.

Comment: while it won't help much in this case, there is no need to save the result of tryCatch to output, then return output.

    safe.predict = function(x){
      tryCatch({
       predict(best.model, test.data.ffdf[x,])
      }, error = function(e) {
           0.50
  }    )
    }

it won't fix your efficiency problem here, but it may help in the future if your function is used inside a tight loop.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not `tryCatch`, which adds only minimal overhead. To illustrate, here's a function that measures how long it takes to generate `n` errors

```
FUN = function(n) 
    system.time(replicate(n, tryCatch(stop(), error=function(...) NA)))[[3]]

> sapply(10^(0:5), FUN)
## [1] 0.001 0.001 0.005 0.055 0.554 5.642
```

you can see that generating 10^5 errors takes about 5.5s. Instead, it's likely that it sometimes takes `predict` a long time to perform a calculation. Maybe the long calculations are ultimately those that throw an error, maybe not. Your best bet is to arrive at a better understanding of `predict`, and either improve its implementation or identify and eliminate before hand, if appropriate, the rows that trigger long-running calculations.

Comment: Interesting - I guess I'm just used to predict() functions being very quick and assumed it was a vectorization problem. It's an nnet model if that makes any difference. I'll take a look at the things you suggest and see if there are any speedups there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've been working on this and have found out that it's actually sapply that's the problem, not the tryCatch function:

```
tries = 1000

time1 = proc.time()[3]
test1 = sapply(1:tries, safe.predict) #this way is very very slow
time2 = proc.time()[3]
print(paste0('Runtime: ',(time2-time1)/60))
```

[1] "Runtime: 1.76163333333333"

```
time1 = proc.time()[3]
test2 = safe.predict(1:tries)# very fast
time2 = proc.time()[3]
print(paste0('Runtime: ',(time2-time1)/60))
```

[1] "Runtime: 0.00740000000000028"

```
#be sure that we are coming to the same answers
sum(test1 == test2) / length(test1)
```

[1] 1

I can see now that using sapply wasn't really necessary, but I thought that that was the whole point of sapply. If anyone has a good explanation for the slowdown, I'd still love to see it in a comment or another answer.

Comment: You may want to look into `system.time()` for timing.